# Aurelia.io: how to navigate to route

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a router.js file with my configured routes:

**routes.js**

```
 export class App {
        configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.title = 'Aurelia';
        config.map([
      {route: ['', `welcome`], name: 'welcome', moduleId: './welcome', nav: true, title:'Welcome'},
      {route: 'http', name: 'http', moduleId: './http', nav: true, title:'HTTPTest'},
      {route: 'users', name: 'users', moduleId: './users', nav: true, title:'Github Users'},
      {route: 'plan', name: 'plan', moduleId:'./dp/plan', nav: true, title:'DPTest'},
      {route: 'user_table', name: 'user_table', moduleId:'./dp/user_table', nav: true, title:'Benutzer'}
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

I want to call one of these routes (`plan`) from a function in `users.js`. Do I have to import {Router} in users.js? Or inject?

Comment: please upvote and accept if this helped you

Answer (score 13):

Either of the following will work

### using `router.navigateToRoute()`

```
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Router)
export class UsersViewModel {
  constructor(router) {
    this.router = router;
  }
  doStuff() {
    this.router.navigateToRoute('plan');
  }
}
```

### using native location

```
export class UsersViewModel {
  doStuff() {
    location.assign('#/users');
  }
}
```