# AureliaJS - navigate to route from div or from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I've just started learning Aurelia JS, and I bumped into a problem.

I have my routes in `app.js` as:

```
  configureRouter(config, router){
    config.title = 'TEST';
    config.map([
      { route: ['','main'], name: 'main', moduleId: './mainpage', nav: true, title:'Main' },
      { route: 'info',     name: 'info', moduleId: './info', nav: true, title:'Info' }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
```

If, in `mainpage.html`, I use this:

```
<div class="button" route-href="route: info;">Go to Info</div>
```

... then nothing happens; if I also add:

```
<div class="button" route-href="route: info;" click.trigger="route: info;">Go to Info</div>
```

... then I get a crash of `au run`. However, if I use the `<a>` element instead:

```
<a route-href="route: info;"><div class="button">Go to Info</div>
```

... then routing/navigation on click works fine - but my CSS style is completely messed up; and I'd rather not style `<a>` specifically for this.

So first question:

- Is it possible to navigate to a route from a `<div>` element; and if so, how?

---

I also tried executing this directly from JavaScript (as per [Aurelia.io: how to navigate to route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501404/aurelia-io-how-to-navigate-to-route), see also [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory src/aurelia-configuration.js · Issue #64 · Vheissu/aurelia-configuration · GitHub](https://github.com/Vheissu/Aurelia-Configuration/issues/64)); so in `mainpage.html` I have this:

```
<div class="button" click.trigger="goInfo()">Go to Info</div>
```

And in `mainpage.js`

```
import { Router } from 'aurelia-routing';

//~ @inject(Router)
export class Main {
  static inject() { return [Router]; }

  constructor(router) {
    this.router = router;
  }

  goInfo() {
    alert("Go Info");
  }
}
```

The `@inject(Router)` fails with something like `inject` not being found, so I used the `static..` syntax as in the tutorial.

As long as I don't have the `import { Router } from 'aurelia-routing';` part, then I can see `goInfo()` fires upon div click, and alert shows. But as soon as I add the `aurelia-routing` part, I get:

```
...
{ uid: 11,
  name: 'writeBundles',
  branch: false,
  error:
   { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '[full project path]/src/aurelia-routing.js']
     errno: -2,
     code: 'ENOENT',
...
```

... and I've even added to `aurelia_project/aurelia.json`:

```
...
        "dependencies": [
...
          "aurelia-route-recognizer",
          "aurelia-router",
          {
            "name": "aurelia-router",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-router/dist/commonjs",
            "main": "index"
          },
          "aurelia-task-queue",
...
```

... but still I get "file not found"... Somehow, the import still insists on finding a file in `src/`, even if that file is in `node_modules/aurelia-router/`

So second question is:

- How can I execute/navigate to a route from JavaScript? Note, I would rather not work via the URL (as in `location.assign('#/info');`)

> EDIT: Just found out it is not called `aurelia-routing` anymore, as in
>   the `mainpage.js` code snippet which I copied from elsewhere - but it
>   is called `aurelia-router` now, as the `aurelia.js` shows. So I just
>   changed the import in `mainpage.js` to `import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';`
>   - and then you do not need the insert between curly
>   braces `{` (the `"name": "aurelia-router",`... part) in `aurelia.js` -
>   and then `this.router.navigateToRoute("info");` works in
>   `mainpage.js`'s `goInfo()` for navigation.
>
> I'd still like to know if it is possible to get a click on a div to
>   navigate using routing with just an attribute, instead of a separate
>   JS function... EDIT2: possibly relevant: [Aurelia delegate vs trigger: how do you know when to use delegate or trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904248/aurelia-delegate-vs-trigger-how-do-you-know-when-to-use-delegate-or-trigger) :
>
> > Only events that bubble can be used with Aurelia's delegate binding
> >     command. The blur, focus, load and unload events do not bubble so
> >     you'll need to use the trigger binding command to subscribe to these
> >     events. ...
> >     iOS does not bubble click events on elements other than `a`,
> >     `button`, `input` and `select`. If you're subscribing to click on a
> >     non-input element like a `div` and are targeting iOS, use the trigger
> >     binding command. More info
> >     [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/click_event_del.html)
> >     and [here](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/263).

Comment: You should probably update your button class so that it works on links too. No reason it should be tied to divs only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `route-href` custom-attribute generates a `href` attribute, which only works for `<a>`. It doesn't work for divs, because `<div href="/page"></div>` is not a valid markup.

To solve this problem, you could create your own custom-attribute. Something like this:

```
import { customAttribute, bindable, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Element, Router)
@customAttribute('go-to-route')
export class GoToRoute {

  @bindable route;
  @bindable params;

  constructor(element, router) {
    this.element = element;
    this.router = router;
  }

  attached() {
    this.element.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.router.navigateToRoute(this.route, this.params);
    });
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<template>
  <require from="./go-to-route"></require>
  <div go-to-route="route: somewhere; params.bind: someParams">Go To Somewhere</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Many thanks @FabioLuz - that looks like a very good solution!